# Broadcast/Event for Voicemail Received Notification Message in Android

Tags: android, events, broadcastreceiver, voicemail

In my application I have blocked incoming calls, so it’s getting redirected to configured voicemail.

As soon as caller place a voicemail, I received a notification message on the device saying “You have new voicemail” and it generates beep.

I would like to disable this beep through my application as soon as device receives voicemail received notification message.

Is there any broadcast or event provided by android?

How can I accomplish this?

My application is built on android version 2.2.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not. Starting in API level 14 (Android 4.0+) they added a broadcast intent of new voicemail messages, but this would only be applicable for devices running Android with an API level of 14 and above.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/VoicemailContract.html

Comment: is it possible on android 4.4?

Comment: @Anuj Not that I know of.